# How to show all assigned issues in Jira

Tags: jira

My list of "Assigned to me" issues in Jira only shows 10 at a time. Is there any way to make it show them all at once so I don't have to page through them all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the number of issues shown anywhere in Jira in your profile under 'Preferences'. However you should not set this too high, because it works as a protection for a single user blocking the complete system when accidentally trying to show thousands of issues.

Comment: Where is the "Preferences" you're talking about? There's a Preferences panel under my profile, but there's nothing relevant there.

Comment: Do you not see "Page Size" under Preferences? Visit User Profile and then look under "Preferences".

Answer (score 0):

In Jira 6:

- click on your picture in the top right corner
- in your profile, scroll down to Preferences
- change the "Page size" parameter

NOTE: this will change your the size for ALL of your lists in Jira.